# what does the acceptance mail from a background verification mean?

Tags: job-acceptance

I have got an offer letter from a company. They asked me to undergo background verification process by providing me a link. I have finished submitting all of my documents. after six hours a person belonging to the background verification company sent me a mail stating that my application for background verification has been accepted.

Does that mean that I have successfully completed the verification process? Or is it just a way of telling me that my application has reached them?

I'm a fresher and I'm not familiar with the process.

Comment: The way you inserted your question into a text box makes it difficult to read. Can you edit that and maybe add some details (one or two short paragraphs).

Answer (score 6):

I would think it means, you have completed all the requirements, and they can now start processing your submissions. It doesn't mean they have completed the background check, it just means they're ready to start it.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a way of telling you that your application has reached them.

Assuming that they have only said that they "have **received** your application successfully" or "your verification application has been accepted"